# IOS, How to connect users directly to each other?

Tags: ios, ipad, video-streaming

I am developing an iPad app and I would like users to be able to video chat. I don't want the video stream to go through a server, I would like it so that users would be able send the video streams directly to each other's iPads. The only thing I would like my server to do is keep track of the users that are online and their IP's.

I am a "newbie" when it comes to developing mobile apps. I would like to know whether or not this is possible, and if it is, how it should be done.

Comment: go with sockets communication, create sockets and move data on them